# Writing a request for the number of hired/fired each year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write an SQL request to count the number of Employees hired/fired each year.

I can have each Employee's dates with this select:

```
SELECT HiredDate, FiredDate FROM Employees;
```

I can list each year with this select:

```
SELECT to_char(e1.HiredDate, 'YYYY') Year FROM Employees e1
UNION
SELECT to_char(e2.FiredDate, 'YYYY') Year FROM Employees e2;
```

But I don't manage to count the number of hired/fired each year.

**EDIT**

Employees sample data:

```
Name   | HiredDate  | FiredDate
--------------------------------
John   | 01/02/2003 | 03/04/2013
Jack   | 05/06/2006 | 07/08/2013
Jean   | 03/04/2006 | null
James  | 01/02/2013 | null
```

Expected results:

```
Year | HiredNumber | FiredNumber
---------------------------------
2003 |           1 |           0
2006 |           2 |           0
2013 |           1 |           2
```

Comment: It's Oracle @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be years with no hiring and years with no firings. So the easiest way to solve this problem is with two sub-queries, one for each count and join them with a full outer join.

```
with e1 as (
    select extract(year from hireddate) as emp_year
           , count(hireddate) as hired_count
    from employees
    where hireddate is not null
    group by extract(year from hireddate)
   )
, e2 as (
    select extract(year from fireddate) as emp_year
           , count(fireddate) as fired_count
    from employees
    where fireddate is not null
    group by extract(year from fireddate)
    )
select coalesce (e1.emp_year, e2.emp_year) as emp_year
       , nvl(e1.hired_count, 0) as hired_count
       , nvl(e2.fired_count, 0) as fired_count
from e1 
     full outer join e2
     on e1.emp_year = e2.emp_year 
order by 1
```

**Notes**

- This will exclude any years with neither hirings nor firings. It's easy enough to generate such things.
- Presumably `hireddate` is mandatory but the not null check is retained for symmetry :)

---

> ". It works well in SQL Developer but can't be set as a Visual datasource"

Here is a variant without the FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select emp_year
       , sum(hired_count) as hired_count 
       , sum(fired_count) as fired_count 
from (
    select extract(year from hireddate) as emp_year 
           , count(hireddate) as hired_count
           , 0 as fired_count
    from employees
    where hireddate is not null
    group by extract(year from hireddate)
    union all
    select extract(year from fireddate) as emp_year
           , 0 as hired_count
           , count(fireddate) as fired_count
    from employees
    where fireddate is not null
    group by extract(year from fireddate)
    )
group by emp_year
order by 1
```

Comment: Great request. It works well in SQL Developer but can't be set as a Visual datasource: "Syntax error : expecting identifier or quoted identifier"

Comment: Hmmm, seems like you're using a tool with a very old client. There's nothing in that query which basically been valid SQL for *years*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Hired' What, to_char(e1.HiredDate, 'YYYY') Year, COUNT(*) TheCount
FROM Employees e1
GROUP BY to_char(e1.HiredDate, 'YYYY')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fired' What, to_char(e2.FiredDate, 'YYYY') Year, COUNT(*) TheCount
FROM Employees e2
GROUP BY to_char(e2.FiredDate, 'YYYY');
```

Comment: In fact, I need 2 numbers each year: number of hired and number of fired.